# How to make a image draggable when it has css as position absolute and it's parent div has css as position relative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This is my part of code:

```html
<div id="canvasImg" class="img-content position-relative">
    <loading></loading>
    <canvas id="Canvas" class="position-absolute"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS used:

```css
.position-relative{
    position: relative;
}
.position-absolute{
    position: absolute;
}
```

After generating the canvas image, I'm creating the some image dynamically.

```js
var createCanvasImgDiv = function (markerDetails) {
            var result = "<img src='../../../../../sharedAssets/images/device_marker.png'"
                    + "class='position-absolute marker-Img'"
                    + "id='" + markerDetails.deviceId + "'"
                    + "name='" + markerDetails.externalName + "'"
                    + "radius='" + markerDetails.radius + "'"
                    + "emailTags='" + markerDetails.emails.join(",") + "'"
                    + "/>";
            return result;
        };
_.map(deviceMarkers, function (tempMarker) {
                var imagDiv = createCanvasImgDiv(tempMarker);
                $("#canvasImg").append(angular.element(imagDiv));
                $compile(angular.element(imagDiv))($scope);
            });
```

Now I want the `<img>` object to move anywhere inside the parent div(id=canvasImg) on drag of mouse. Also I want the mouse position when it drops.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [jquery-ui draggable widget](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to achieve this.

```js
$("#image").draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
$("#image").on("dragstop", function(event, ui) {
  alert("mouse position: X:" + event.pageX + ", Y:" + event.pageY);
});
```

```css
.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}
.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasImg" class="img-content position-relative" style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000000;">
  <loading></loading>
  <canvas id="Canvas" class="position-absolute" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <img id="image" class="position-relative" src="http://wallpaper.sc/en/ipad/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ipad-2048x2048-thumbnail_00721-256x256.jpg" style="width:25px;height:25px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi!! Actually my question is not for dragging the canvas. I want to move the <img> attributes which are created parallel to canvas.

Comment: suppose the DOM is like this,
<div id="canvasImg" class="img-content position-relative">
    <loading></loading>
    <canvas id="Canvas" class="position-absolute"></canvas>
    <img id="image" class="position-relative" src=""something" />
</div>

then I wanted to move this <img>(id=image)

Comment: I'm getting a error like,"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function". Info: I'm generating the <img> attribute dynamically

Comment: no sir, when I'm trying your solution in my code, it's throwing that error

Comment: did you add these libraries:`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133480/discussion-between-aminur-rashid-and-suparna).